# Tensorflow Convolution tf.nn.conv2d argument strides

Tags: image, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

> def conv2d(x, W):
>   return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
>   padding='SAME')

Can someone please kindly help me to understand, what is the functionality of strides in this place?. If possible, please explain each argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of stride is how you jump forward in a dimension, your dimension are [batch, height, width, color].

- If you set strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], the filter window will move 1 batch, 1 height pixel, 1 width pixel and 1 color pixel
- If you set strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], the filter window will move 1 batch, 2 height pixel, 2 width pixel and 1 color pixel (Imagine that you have an image and a window, after processing, you move the window 2 pixel to the left and 2 pixel down)
  The effect will result in the output with smaller size output (~1/2 height and 1/2 width)

The padding='SAME' will pad the border of image with zeros so that you can do convolution on the top-left pixel.

Other argument explain can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d).